# Find position with the concurrence of a separator in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Good morning, I was looking for a formula to help me with this in Excel 2016, but I did not succeed, I have this text in a cell:

```
CF|0101|2019-02-05|01|F007-00000018|PEN|20539043782|6|20479636304|SERVICENTRO SANTA MARIA EIRL|CARRET. JAEN SAN IGNACIO KM 25- CAS. YANUYACU- JAEN||||||||6.10|33.90|6.10|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|33.90|40.00|0.00|0.00|40.00|1000|CUARENTA CON 00/100 SOLES   |||||||M5K-788|
```

I want to extract the text with the help of the separator "|" and in a not so long formula, try with FIND, but the formula becomes very long after the third linked search, is there any way to obtain the position of the separator by number of concurrency? , something like this:

Searched text;Cell;Repetition number(concurrency of simbol)

=FORMULA("|";A1;2)

Result: 8

Or simulate something like this?

From already thank you very much.

**UPDATE

I will not use all the texts among the "|", that's why my need to obtain the position of the separators to extract only the text I need, since the tool "Text to Columns "forces you to give a position for all the separate texts.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not very clear with the information you gave. Do you simply want to split the data up, using Text to Columns? Are you trying to get only text, without `|`?

Comment: That is my final goal, to extract the text without the "|", but first I would need the position of the "|".

Comment: Then, as @BruceWayne suggests, use Text to Columns with "|" as the delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want a formula that will separate everything into unique Columns. Then perhaps you should look at a custom formula. Here is a quick example of UDF that can parse data based on the "|"

```
Function SplitData(rng As String, Character As Variant, Position As Integer) As Variant

    SplitData = Split(rng, Character)(Position - 1)

End Function
```

Once this function has been placed into a VBA module, then you can call this from any cell within that workbook.

To keep things simple here is the breakout...

`=SplitData( <THE CELL THAT CONTAINS THE DATA YOU WISH TO PARSE>, <THE CHARACTER YOU WANT TO USE AS YOUR DELIMITER>, <POSITION IN WHICH YOU WANT TO DISPLAY THE TEXT (Valid Numbers start at 1+> )`

The POSITION Point is used to display which section of the text. For example based on your example provided, if you populated the following...

`=SplitData(A1, "|", 1) == "CF"`

By the way, if you are dead set on finding the location of the "|", then how about using the `=Search()` formula. This will easily hunt do the character position of the first "|", but with a little bit of work you can get it to display other locations.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7), you can use `Text to Columns`:

> Select the cell or column that contains the text you want to split.
>
> Select Data > Text to Columns.
>
> In the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select Delimited > Next.
>
> Select the Delimiters for your data. You'd want to put a `|` in the "Other" area.
>
> Select Next.
>
> Select the Column data format or use what Excel chose for you.
>
> Select the Destination, which is where you want the split data to
>   appear on your worksheet.
>
> Select Finish.

Or - if you literally just need all that in a single string, without `|`, you can use `SUBSTITUTE()`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|"," ")
```

Comment: I had already tried with that tool, my error, I did not add that I will not use all the texts among the "|", that's why my need to obtain the position of the separators to extract only the text I need, since the tool "Text to Columns "forces you to give a position for all the separate texts.

Comment: @DalexA then please edit your original post with more clarity, and example input/output.